# Why is my Swift ternary operator not working?

Tags: swift, loops, conditional-operator

I'm on my 2nd day learning Swift and I have the following doubt regarding the ternary operator.

I have the following code:

```
var list = [2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 9]

var sumOfEven = 0
var productOfOdd = 1

for item in list {
  item % 2 == 0 ? sumOfEven += item : productOfOdd *= item
}
```

It's pretty self explanatory but to avoid any doubts the program should add all the even numbers on an array of `Int` and multiply all the odd numbers.

However I'm having the following code when I run the above:

```
error: result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '()' and 'Int'
  (item % 2 == 0) ? sumOfEven += item : productOfOdd *= item
```

How do I have mismatching types?! I've tried declaring both `sumOfEven` and `productOfOdd`  as `Int` and `Double` but still doesn't work...

Everything works fine if I replace my `If...Else` for:

```
for item in list {
  if item % 2 == 0 {
    sumOfEven += item
  } else {
    productOfOdd *= item
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler needs a little help, the spaces in your ternary are causing it to get confused due to the way that operator precedence is implemented in the language. If you wrap your statements in parentheses then it will compile and do what you expect.

Also there is property that will allow you to check whether something is a multiple(of:), it can make for easier to read code, though you can use `item % 2 == 0` if you wish and it will still work.

```
var list = [2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 9]

var sumOfEven = 0
var productOfOdd = 1

for item in list {
    item.isMultiple(of: 2) ? (sumOfEven += item) : (productOfOdd *= item)
}

print(sumOfEven)     // 12
print(productOfOdd)  // 27
```

However, ternaries can make for harder to understand code. This would be better written as an `if-else` like you had written in your question.

```
for item in list {
    if item % 2 == 0 {  // you could use item.isMultiple(of: 2) 
        sumOfEven += item
    } else {
        productOfOdd *= item
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s behaving exactly correctly actually. This is just how the operator precedence is defined by the language.

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) BTW, I would suggest NOT using the ternary operator in a case like this, when the code in the two cases has side-effects. It reads much easier to just use an if statement in this case. (Prefer readability/maintainability over terseness/slick code)

Comment: That worked thanks! Any particular reason why this happens? For example, I'm pretty sure this wouldn't happen in JS...

Comment: @DuncanC I agree it is better to have code that is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: @DuncanC which be the ideal situations to and not to use the ternary operator? Any article or similar you could point me to so I can understand better?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the type system. It’s about the operator precedence  being such that the conditional operator is binding more strongly to `productOfOdd` than the `*=`.

Answer (score 1):

It's often considered ok to use ternary operator *only if* there are no *side-effects*, like mutation, or printing, involved. If it's just evaluating an expression's value to be either A or B, then you are ok. You could do it like this:

```
let list = [2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 9]
let (sumsOfEven, productOfOdd) = list.reduce((0, 1)) { (result, item) in
item.isMultiple(of: 2) ?
    (result.0 + item, result.1) : (result.0, result.1 * item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say every time you go to use the ternary operator, stop and ask yourself, does it make the code easier to follow & maintain? Start from the assumption that the answer is no, and only use it in those cases where it really does improve readability.

One thing I would avoid is cases that have side effects as in the example you gave (if the expression is true, it does adds to sumOfEvent, if it's false, it multiplies productOfOdd by some value.)

Instead, use it in cases like this:

```
var useFirst = true

var firstAddend = 1
var secondAddend = 2

let aValue += useFirst ? firstAddend : secondAddend
```

But only if it makes the code clearer and easier to maintain.

Is that clearer than:

```
if useFirst {
    addValue += firstAddend
} else {
    addValue += secondAddend
}
```

(Not really, no.)

---

### Edit

In the example above, one argument for the ternary operator version is the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. In the if/else version, the variable `addValue` appears twice. If at some future date you change that variable, you'd have to remember to change it in both places, or risk introducing a bug. I personally think in a case like this readability is much more important, and find the if/else version a lot easier to read. (And I've been programming in C-like languages that include the ternary operator professionally for ≈35 years.)